# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift

I have this error when I try add some values to mainArray. 
this is MainViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var mainArray:[TaskModel] = []
```

here is addTaskViewController

```
var mainVC: ViewController!

  @IBAction func addBarButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var newTask = TaskModel(value: self.taskTextField.text)
    mainVC.mainArray.append(newTask)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that an optional is nil - basing on what I see in your code, I'd say that this property:

```
var mainVC: ViewController!
```

has not properly been initialized, which means it is nil

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers, I fix it by this funcion:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AddViewControllerSegue" {
        let addTaskVC:AddViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AddViewController
        addTaskVC.mainVC = self
    }
}
```

and then I add to my addButton:

```
@IBAction func addBarButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var newTask = TaskModel(value: taskTextField.text)
    mainVC.mainArray.append(newTask)
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

And it works great! :)